# Web page not resizing on mobile - Bootstrap 5 + particles.js

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get web page automatically resized to fit on a mobile.
On Lagre Screen it looks good, but on mobile screen it is mixed up. Font is on mobile screen to big and not in center

If anyone has any ideas what I should do please let me know.

here is link with code

```
jsfiddle.net/osmania/smc3rf2k/4/
```

tnx a lot

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you exactly want? You want to make particles.js div to be fit on full screen of mobile.

Comment: On Lagre Screen it looks good, but on mobile screen it is mixed up. Font is on mobile screen to big and not in center

Answer (score 0):

To fix the text in the second section getting messed up all you need to do is remove the *height* property on your .middle2 class:

```css
.middle2 {
  /* height: 40vh; * <-- REMOVE THIS /
}
```

By removing the height property, it allows the content to take up as much vertical space as it needs. This solution works for both your desktop and mobile site, so you don't need to use any media queries.

http://jsfiddle.net/og4ye0t6/

Comment: on large screen second section does not have height: 40, how can i keep 40 height, what about first section. n Mobile screen does not look nice. font is to large and not in the middle